# How to add new item to hyperlink menu in Outlook 2007 with VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I need to add new item to the hyperlink menu in Outlook 2007 (now it contains items like Copy, Select Hyperlink, Open Hyperlink, Copy Hyperlink, Who is).

How can I do it?
(it should be a VBA macro added to Outlook)

Comment: Don't believe that this is impossible ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to do the same with VBA. Even MS doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The definitive article on Outlook and CommandBar objects is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201095).

The code at the end of the article that you can run in Excel to get a listing of all the CommandBar objects is following.  Note that you have to have the Outlook Library in the References in VBA to get this to run:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oOutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim I As Long
Dim iRowCount As Long
Dim oItm As Object ' so it'll handle varying item types
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Sub GetOutlookCommandBarIDs()

If MsgBox("This will clear the current worksheet, OK to continue?", vbOKCancel) = 1 Then

   Cells.Select
   Selection.ClearContents

   iRowCount = 0
   Set oSheet = ActiveSheet
   Set oOutApp = New Outlook.Application
   Set oNS = oOutApp.Session

   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Mail Message"
   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olPostItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Post"
   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olContactItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Contact"
   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olDistributionListItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Distribution List"
   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Appointment"
   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Task"
   Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olJournalItem)
   GetInspectorIDs oItm, "Journal Entry"

   Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
   GetExplorerIDs oFld, "Mail Folder"
   Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
   GetExplorerIDs oFld, "Contact Folder"
   Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
   GetExplorerIDs oFld, "Calendar Folder"
   Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
   GetExplorerIDs oFld, "Task Folder"
   Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJournal)
   GetExplorerIDs oFld, "Journal Folder"
   Set oFld = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderNotes)
   GetExplorerIDs oFld, "Notes Folder"

   Selection.AutoFilter
   Cells.Select
   Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
   Range("A1").Select

   MsgBox "The spreadsheet is complete."

End If

End Sub


Sub GetInspectorIDs(oItm, sType As String)
   Dim oCBs As Office.CommandBars
   Dim oCtl As Office.CommandBarControl
   Set oCBs = oItm.GetInspector.CommandBars
   For I = 1 To 35000
      Set oCtl = oCBs.FindControl(, I)
      If Not (oCtl Is Nothing) Then
         iRowCount = iRowCount + 1
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 1) = "Inspector"
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 2) = sType
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 3) = oCtl.Parent.Name
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 4) = oCtl.Caption
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 5) = CStr(I)
      End If
   Next
End Sub


Sub GetExplorerIDs(oFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder, sType As String)
   Dim oCBs As Office.CommandBars
   Dim sFilter As String
   Dim oCtl As Office.CommandBarControl
   Set oCBs = oFld.GetExplorer.CommandBars
   For I = 1 To 35000
      Set oCtl = oCBs.FindControl(, I)
      If Not (oCtl Is Nothing) Then
         iRowCount = iRowCount + 1
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 1) = "Explorer"
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 2) = sType
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 3) = oCtl.Parent.Name
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 4) = oCtl.Caption
         oSheet.Cells(iRowCount, 5) = CStr(I)
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

The excerpt of the output that will help you is:

```
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  Te&xt Box          139
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Symbol...         308
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Tip Wizard 5      345
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Object...         546
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  Boo&kmark...       758
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  Date and &Time...  768
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Field...          772
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  Attach             1079
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Hyperlink...      1576
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  New Co&mment       1589
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  It&em...           2505
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Remove Hyperlink  3626
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Calendar...       11496
Inspector   Mail Message    Insert  &Picture           30180
```

So you'd access it something like:

```
 Dim oItm As Object
 Dim oExp As Outlook.Explorer
 Dim oBar As Office.CommandBar
 Dim oOutApp As Object

 Set oOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 Set oItm = oOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 Set oExp = Outlook.ActiveExplorer
 Set oBar = oItm.GetInspector.CommandBars.Item("Insert")

 oBar.Controls.Add (blahblahblah)
```

**Note:** I was only able to test things in Outlook 2010.

Comment: thanks. I've run the macro in Excel/Outlook 2007. It works, but it doesn't return Hyperlink menu items (when you view the message, not create new one) - what you've listed in your initial message.

Comment: @LA, well since you only want to add things, if you can access the "Insert" tab you're probably close.  I can't figure out the exact details for you since I don't use 2007.  I hope this gets you closer to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206754(v=office.12).aspx ?

Comment: Thanks. Surely I've seen that. But there is no Hyperlink menu object.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have a definite answer for you, but hopefully I can point you in the right direction.

[This forum will hopefully be useful](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/Add-Menu-items-Tools-Menu-Outlook-2007--ftopict994678.html), it looks like they're doing the same thing there (albeit with a different menu).

And if you need some basics help, here are two MSDN blogs talking about Outlook and VBA macros in general:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2007/05/23/adding-a-vba-macro-to-outlook.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2007/12/11/office-2007-outlook2007-macros-vba-how-to-work-better-with-categories.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @erekalper. Different menu - is the main point, I don't know how to get hyperlink menu object.